# HTML renders undefined line through element?

Tags: html, css

The following [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ngyoyzda/3/) generates 3 boxes with a glyphicon icon, text and title. (NOTE: with the JSFiddle, you need to have the display window in the medium+ size bracket to generate the correct layout). These are responsive and use the bootstrap framework. When I preview the result, I sometimes get a line under the glyph. What is causing this? I get it in both Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, however, sometimes when I zoom in, it disappears, then if I zoom in more, it reappears? Other times when I load the same file, it doesn't show.

[image: line]

```
  <div class="row Page2">
    <div class="col-sm-2 margin"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn glyphicon-bordered"></span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 margin"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok glyphicon-bordered"></span>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 margin"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
      <div class="glyphicon-ring"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone glyphicon-bordered"></span>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 margin"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 margin"></div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
            <h3><strong>Simple</strong></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 eqheight1">
            <p class>Text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

the css:

```
  .Page2 > * {
    border: 5px solid white;
    background: #3DBEAF;
  }
  .Page2 > *:nth-child(-n+6) {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  .Page2 > *:nth-last-child(-n+6) {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }

  .eqheight1,
  .eqheight2,
  .eqheight3 {
  background: #3DBEAF;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Any ideas, or know how I can test this further?

Comment: Try using the `z-index` css property. (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) It basically allows you to say to render the image in front of the line.

Comment: The JSFiddle you linked to isn't replicating the issue, could you update it to match your problem ?

Comment: @LoremIpsum I am not sure what is causing the issue and it is temperamental, so it doesn't show up all the time...

Comment: Sub-pixel rounding would be my best guess.

Comment: @Paulie_D if you look at the image, it seems as though the line extends beyond the colored backgrounds?